# Restrict IAM user to access specific Cognito user pool(s)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have three user pools in Cognito - one for DEV, one for UAT and one for PROD. I have crated an IAM user to programatically access the user pools using the Cognito API. This works fine but I want to restrict this user to only be able to access a single one of the user pools.

I will then create an additional two IAM users for the other two pools.

Cognito supports "Resource-level permissions" but I am struggling to understand how I can configure this to restrict a user to a single user pool.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how you go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "cognito-idp:ListUserPools",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "cognito-idp:*",
        "Resource": <Pool ARN>
    }
    ]
}
```

If you don't want user to be able to list all pools just get rid of the List user pools part. Also, I have put `cognito-idp:*` just for demonstration purposes. You should specify what all rights you want to give.